# Deployment of Angular 7 PWA application in Tomcat Apache production server

Tags: angular, apache, tomcat, progressive-web-apps, angular-pwa

I've created an Angular PWA application and built it by running: `ng build --prod`.

It has built the production ready application successfully.
I've ran the built application in local by running command: `http-server -o`, It was running as expected.

**Problem:**
When I've deployed in production's server tomcat apache webapp directory and ran it I am getting: `Service worker is not registered or does not control the Start URL`.

Service worker is not registering in my production environment.

Please Help me Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have HTTPS connection to register a service worker. But still it works on localhost without HTTPS.

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

Comment: Thank you, So is there any way to register a service worker in http connection

Comment: got it abraham, thanx