# Angular Service Worker offline support not working when deployed on tomcat

Tags: java, angular, angular-service-worker

I have an angular app which we are deploying on tomcat(using war). I am adding the offline support to the app using angular-sw.
The application is accessed using the context-path(say showcase-app)

The problem which I am facing right now is that when I try to access app(offline mode using chrome dev tool) using below urls, then its working fine:

http://localhost:8080/showcase-app/

http://localhost:8080/showcase-app/index.html (redirected to http://localhost:8080/showcase-app/)

When I press F5, then I am getting http 504

If I try http://localhost:8080/showcase-app, 504 error is thrown

I feel that its something to do with the routing but not sure what exactly the problem is.

Here is my generated ngsw.json file(Remove the unnecessary css and js urls)

```
{
  "configVersion": 1,
  "timestamp": 1565693252354,
  "index": "/showcase-app/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/showcase-app/favicon.ico",
        "/showcase-app/index.html",
        "/showcase-app/main-es2015.f5103b4162e6ae00889a.js",
        "/showcase-app/main-es5.0b19cc7e5eb478145768.js",
        "/showcase-app/polyfills-es2015.e35a976998ea3f8206df.js",
        "/showcase-app/polyfills-es5.6e97d82e42cdf0e046a3.js",
        "/showcase-app/runtime-es2015.3d53808bc2188f4243c7.js",
        "/showcase-app/runtime-es5.f1b869bd6638a324a133.js",
        "/showcase-app/scripts.385aa2cec8cdc651bfad.js",
        "/showcase-app/styles.5b950d38f1d7a3ba6506.css",
      ],
      "patterns": []
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "urls": [
        "/showcase-app/CardObject.f4ac54620cd0f92eb623.png"
      ],
      "patterns": []
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [],
  "hashTable": {
    "/showcase-app/CardObject.f4ac54620cd0f92eb623.png": "425c1e1cfed36bea7d7d3637fa95c147bd5480d3"
  },
  "navigationUrls": [
    {
      "positive": true,
      "regex": "^\\/.*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*\\.[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*$"
    },
    {
      "positive": false,
      "regex": "^\\/(?:.+\\/)?[^/]*__[^/]*\\/.*$"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using Angular 8

Comment: I don't think this problem has to do with PWA. This problem is likely because you are deploying in a sub url. Probably you need to specify this in base and .htaccess

Comment: @SGalea, Can you please clarify a bit more? Where I need to specify and what?
I am using Apache tomcat server and not sure whether .htaccess file is available to it or not.

Comment: Replicate the issue on stackblitz.com because I'm just taking a guess. The thing is for your index.html to be under showcase-app you have some customizations that we also need to know in order to help you

Comment: Also PWA's don't work well unless https. Try to deploy directly under http://localhost:8080 without sub-folder to start troubleshooting.

Comment: I am trying to reproduce the issue at stackblitz.com but I think its something to do with the tomcat deployment. Also I can't deploy directly under tomcat as it try to deploy all the subfolders separately

Comment: I do not have TomCat to test on but usually when it i sunder a sub-folder and a refresh issue it is usually the same answer I gave here also. However try without a PWA as they don't work well if not served over https https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57472330/why-page-show-404-when-manually-refreshing-url-in-browser-angular-7-on-jboss-ser/57475117?noredirect=1#comment101426018_57475117

Comment: Without pwa, refresh is working on my app. 
It may be with the routing in respect to the service worker. Any idea how to configure fallback routing angular service worker?

Comment: check your network tab and to the F5 and see if it is trying to access the back-end

Comment: Also check if your service worker is being registered in your browser. if you are not running it in https you will have problems

Comment: These are the 2 entries in the network tab.

`⚙ showcase-app/ GET (failed) fetch ngsw-worker.js:2709 0 B 2 ms ⚙ ngsw.json?ngsw-cache-bust=0.8220167373795033 GET (failed) fetch ngsw-worker.js:2709 0 B 2 ms`

Comment: Service worker is registered...I am accessing it on localhost

Answer (score 0):

According to this doc you'll need https to work with service workers... anyway if you try it in your local tomcat it will work...

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/#you_need_https

> Found in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56376214/5360905